# Returning Sin[t] from package turns into Sin[scope`t]

Tags: functions, packages, variable

I have a function in scope that returns an expression with a variable `t`

```
BeginPackage["Pkg`"]
F1::usage = "";
Begin["scope`"]
F1[x_] := Sin[t + x];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

When I use it from outside

```
In[159]:= F1[2]
Out[159]= Sin[2 + scope`t]
```

I can Replace `scope`t`to`t` outside

```
In[169]:= F1[2] /. scope`t -> t
Out[169]= Sin[2 + t]
```

But is there any way to replace it from the inside of Package ?

I have tried replacing `t` with `"t"`

```
BeginPackage["Pkg`"]
F1::usage = "";
Begin["scope`"]
F1[x_] := Sin[t + x] /. t -> "t";
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

This looks like it works

```
In[223]:= F1[2]
Out[223]= Sin[2 + t]
```

However it is actually `Sin[2 + "t"]` So I cannot plot it with variable `t`

```
Plot[F1[2], {t, 0, 200}]
```

doesn't plot anything

Comment: You need to define t as a public variable as well as F1, with a usage message in the same way.

Comment: @KraZug You should write your comment up as an answer, it seems like the most elegant solution & helped me out with a similar problem.

Comment: @Chris The reason I didn't was because I assumed that the question would get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`t` needs to be an argument of your function `F1` like so:

```
BeginPackage["Pkg`"]
F1::usage = "";
Begin["scope`"]
F1[x_, t_] := Sin[t + x];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

The calling it:

```
F1[x, t]
(*Sin[t + x]*)
```

Comment: Is there any way to force t to be a variable not a value so that it doesn't conflict with a global variable `t` declared in user's notebook ?

Comment: @NeelBasu, I don't understand what you are looking for. Can you show (code) what is conflicting in this case?

Comment: If I have `t=42` in my Notebook prior invoking `F1[x, t]` it will use that t and return `Sin[x + 42]`. So is there any way such that user is forced to pass a variable only. or the symbol is used instead of its value even if a predefined variable is passed.

Comment: Use something like 't_Symbol' in the definition of F1. Have look in the documentation under pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a usage definition the variable `t` as well as `F1` (and in general, anything you want to return from your package)

```
BeginPackage["Pkg`"]
F1::usage = "";
t::usage = "time variable";
Begin["scope`"]
F1[x_] := Sin[t + x];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Then the `t` that is returned works fine.

Comment: If the user code uses a variable `t` it use that instead

Comment: This code does not work when there is a global definition for t. E.g. try `t=1` and then run your code.